# how to schedule to run a shell script on a particular day of a month

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I want to schedule to run a shell script on a Thursday which comes after the second Tuesday of every month. How to schedule this in crontab?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry Arpit, I couldn't comeup with the logic.

Answer (score 3):

The second Tuesday of the month will occur between the 8th and the 14th inclusive, so set the day-of-week field to 4 (Thursday), and the day-of-month field to 10-16 (that is, a range adjusted to be two days after the range of the month's second Tuesday).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `8-14` instead of `10-16` ?

Comment: @Jahid, no, because the OP wants the Thu after the second Tue, so the day range needs to be shifted forward two days (from 8–14 to 10–16).  I edited the answer to be a bit clearer on that.